# Polygon not showing up after setAttribute HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, shapes

I want to dynamically create a triangle in my html code, that I later want to modify and work with.
But already from the start, it doesn't show up.

The onclick function triggers correctly and the new object appears in the html, but the object is nowhere visible.

```js
function start_dreiecke() {

    var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
    var polygon = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "polygon");

    polygon.setAttribute('id', 'triangle_' + '01');
    polygon.setAttribute('style', 'width:200px;height:200px;');
    polygon.setAttribute('points', '1000,779 100,779 550,0');
    polygon.setAttribute("style","fill:yellow;stroke:yellow;stroke-width:1;fill-rule:nonzero;");

    svg.appendChild(polygon);
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(svg);
}
```

```css
#canvas 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}

svg
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<h1>Schnittstellendreieck</h1>
<p>Hier ist eine Baustelle für bessere Baustellen.</p>

<!-- Hier werden die Dreiecke generiert. -->

<div id="button">
  <h2 onclick="start_dreiecke()">Start Dreieck</h2>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<h3 id="clicked"></h3>
```

Why doesn't my triangle show up?

Comment: A `<canvas>` element’s content is only [for showing fallback content](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#alternative_content) if the `<canvas>` element is not supported by the browser or if JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `canvas` HTML element is not supposed to have children. It's a kind of whiteboard where lines and shapes don't have any DOM representation. On the other hand, `svg` has a DOM representation, so just remove the `canvas` and append the `svg` somewhere else in the DOM.

```js
function start_dreiecke() {

    var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
    var polygon = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "polygon");

    polygon.setAttribute('id', 'triangle_' + '01');
    polygon.setAttribute('style', 'width:200px;height:200px;');
    polygon.setAttribute('points', '1000,779 100,779 550,0');
    polygon.setAttribute("style","fill:yellow;stroke:yellow;stroke-width:1;fill-rule:nonzero;");

    svg.appendChild(polygon);
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
}
```

```css
#canvas 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}

svg
{
    position:absolute;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<h1>Schnittstellendreieck</h1>
<p>Hier ist eine Baustelle für bessere Baustellen.</p>

<!-- Hier werden die Dreiecke generiert. -->

<button onclick="start_dreiecke()" id="button">Start Dreieck</button>

<h3 id="clicked"></h3>
```